# How to disable Chrome find text from matching text on a `position: fixed` element?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, find

I have a Toc (an element in html), with `position: fixed`.

- (which means, it moves along to stay in position as you scroll)

I want to disable Chrome find Text from matching text on that Toc element.

- (by using javascript, if possible)
- because

  1. I dont need search on it
  2. its indicator on scroll bar is disrupting for seeing other matches.

--

As image shows::

[image: image: find text]

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by preventDefault().

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

In this code, if Ctrl+F is pressed, it will prevent default behavior of the browser - find text.

Comment: Wouldnt it completely disable the `find text` functionality? I still need to use `find`, but just not match text on a specific element. (I will update the question for clarification)